# How to count repeated records in sql?

Tags: sql

Hi have a table name is Pattern

```
S.No      type      Id_Section
    1          A        IPS
    2          A        IPS
    3          A        IPS
    4          A        IPS
    1          B        IPS
    2          B        IPS
    3          B        IPS
    1          C        IPS
    2          C        IPS
```

I want a query to count records  where type "A" ...I tried some examples..But i am getting whole records count..Please any one help me..

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT count(*) FROM Pattern where type = "A"`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to get a count per type you'd write

```
SELECT
    type ,
    count (S.No) Kount
FROM  
     Pattern
GROUP BY
     type
```